# IOS/SWIFTПоиск устройства по UUID

Tags: ios, swift

Есть bluetooth устройство, Есть его SERVICE_UUID, CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, BEACON_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID. Хочу сделать так чтобы при поиске устройств, было видно только мое устройство. Пробовал делать CBUUID из SERVICE_UUID и отправлять его в scanForPeripherals, но после этого вообще ни одно устройство не находится. Что я делаю не так? Вот код, в устройстве используется Arduino.

```
enum DeviceBluetoothServices {
        static let SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")
        static let CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = CBUUID(string: "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8")
        static let BEACON_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = CBUUID(string: "19fbc032-c156-4861-a314-aa098a0f2f7f")

        static let characteristics: [CBUUID] = [ SERVICE_UUID, CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, BEACON_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID ]
    }


manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: DeviceBluetoothServices.characteristics, options: nil )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете массив с характеристиками в метод, который принимает `services` identifiers.

На характеристики мы смотрим уже после того, как получили сервисы.

Их можно будет передать в `peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(characteristicsIdentifiers, for: service)`

Почитайте эту статью https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor . В ней есть примеры с использованием поиска конкретного сервиса с конкретными характеристиками.